# Setup L2TP Ubuntu Server without IPSec (yes I know thats very odd)

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, vps, l2tp, xl2tpd

Im trying to tunnell my traffic from a bunch of low end mikrotik routers through a L2PT tunnel, and these routers are not powerful enough to run encryption.  I have Ubuntu 20.04 VPS, and have installed xl2tpd.  Ive been trying to follow this guide: https://smekkley.wordpress.com/tag/l2tp-without-ipsec/

Here are my configs so far:

```
[global]
port = 1701

[lns default]
ip range = 10.10.10.2-10.10.10.254
local ip = 10.10.10.1
require chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = no
name = l2tpd
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
length bit = yes
```

and the PPP options file

```
+mschap-v2
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
noccpauthcrtsctsidle 1800
defaultroute
mtu 1280
mru 1280
proxyarp
lcp-echo-failure 4
lcp-echo-interval 30
connect-delay 5000
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

and then my chaps-secrets

```
"username" l2tpd "password" *
```

I have my ipv4 forwarding rule setup, and port 1701 open in ufw.  What am I missing here? my client will not connect!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same questions I have practically the same setup except that my routers are archer c50's that offered only the l2pt option, does any one have an answer please.